# Specify Columns and Rows from Property Values in Query Language from Azure Stream Analytics

Tags: azure, azure-stream-analytics

Hope I'm describing this correctly:
Is it possible to create columns and rows only from property values?
With my current code, the columns are the property names, and the rows are the values.
[Current Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FTHVn.png)
[Preferred Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/93YwT.png)

JSON Message:
{
  deviceName: "FillerDevice",
  timestamp: "2019-07-17T16:42:10Z",
  tags: [
    {
       do4: 1
    },
    {
    do5: 0
    }
  ]
}

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please include the Current Output and Preferred Output in the body of the Question rather than linking to pictures. SO seems to frown on links that are key to understanding the question.

Comment: Hi,not sure what you want. Please provide your input and desired output so that we could help you.

Comment: Hi, Jeff. I was trying to include the images in the body, but "[I] need at least 10 reputation to post images."

Comment: Jay, the current input is the JSON Message. The current and preferred outputs are the links in the body.

Answer (score 1):

The following approach creates columns per defined keys of properties within an array.

You could do it with an User Defined Function assuming you know what keys to look for beforehand:

**ASA Query**

```
select
    Input.deviceName,
    Input.timestamp,
    UDF.ExtractData(Input.tags, 'do4') as do4,
    UDF.ExtractData(Input.tags, 'do5') as do5
into Output
from Input
```

**UDF**

```
function ExtractData(array, key) {
    'use strict';

    var value = null;

    if (array != null
        && key != null
        && Array.isArray(array)
        && isString(key)) {

        // find all objects indexes of objects in the array with the key
        var indexes = [], i;
        for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (array[i].hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                indexes.push(i);
            }  
        }

        if (indexes.length > 0) {
            // in case it occurs multiple times take the first one
            // you could also implement other conditions here
            var indexToUse = indexes[0];

            // set return value
            value = array[indexToUse][key];
        } 
    }

    return value;
}


function isString(value) {
    return typeof value === 'string' || value instanceof String;
}
```